# Linux sftp -- how to add new user to access exist directory with write permission?

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

I have built a website and I can access and edit the website'files on server via the root user. The current file and directory structures are not changeable. Now I am hiring a webpage designer to help me re-design some pages, I am going to let the designer edit the files directly on the server. So I need to add a new user and restrict the new user to access only three front-end related directory. And the three directories are not in the same directory, like below:

/home/www/application/index/view (html files)

/home/www/public/js (js files)

/home/www/public/css (css files)

The first step adding new user has been accomplished. But the problems are:

1 how to let the new user access above directories with write permission?

2 how to bind above three directories to the new user? (It seems ChrootDirectory can only bind one directory.)

Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Give it a close vote on SU, then.

Comment: Sorry for the crossposting. I am not very familiar with the Stack Exchange family. I posted this question in Superuser first. Then I realized it is not the right place for this question. So I posted it here......

Answer (score 0):

After many times of researches and tries, I have it worked. The approach may have many disadvantages, as a beginner, it has been the most satisfied result that I can get. My steps are as follows:

1 Add a new user test1.
2 Make a root folder for test1.
3 Make three sub-folders, each will map to the corresponding exist folder we are going to let test1 access.
4 Make the three exist folders writable.
5 mount --bind each exist folder to corresponding sub-folder.
6 Done.

After above steps, user test1 will be able to access above three exist folders and contained files, and then edit.